# socket.io - What can cause 'client not handshaken client should reconnect'?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use socket.io 0.9.6, and I get many logs `client not handshaken client should reconnect` from real users, but I could never reproduce it myself.

I tried many browsers (IE8-9, FF3.6-13, Chrome, Opera 11), I tried simulating high pings (up to 4s), but nothing to do, I never get this log.

What can I do to reproduce this ?

Comment: Perhaps your app is standing behind nginx or something else which does not support HTTP/1.1?

Comment: There is nothing in front of the app (except a Linux firewall)

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by antivirus software or firewall on the client side. I had the same problem with avast antivirus.

Possible solution: Use several commonly known ports such as 80, 25, 443, 843, 110, 5190, 5222, 5223, etc. using port forwarding on the server side. If connection fails on client side, try to change port and connect again. It works for me.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what Avast was doing?

Comment: I just had this problem coming from IE8 (compatibility mode disabled), it just went crazy! but browsing away stopped the problem. At the same time Im running Opera, Chrome and Firefox and this does not happen. (xhr-polling)